# Creating generic KafkaTemplate in spring boot Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring Kafka to implement Kafka, which is cool. Now I want to create a generic Kafka template to send the message.

Something like this

```
    public class ProductProducer<T> implements IProductProducer{
        private final KafkaTemplate<String, T> _template;
    
        public ProductProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, T> _template) {
            this._template = _template;
        }
    
        @Override
        public ProductViewModel GetProduct(String id) {
            this._template.send(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, id);
            return new ProductViewModel("","",0,"");
        } 

       @Override
        public void AddProduct(ProductViewModel product) {
           this._template.send(ProductTopicConstants.ADD_PRODUCT, product);
        }

    }
```

For Kafka Key is always String, but the data might be a different models.

I get the error as

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you define the field _template  as generic,it means _template  can only send same data type.U can define _template` as

```
private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> _template;
```

and then add a new private generic method

```
private  <T> void send(String key ,T t){
    this._template.send(key, t);
}
```

the whole class defination:

```
public class ProductProducer implements IProductProducer{
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> _template;

    public ProductProducer(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> _template) {
        this._template = _template;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewModel GetProduct(String id) {
        this.send(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, id);
        return new ProductViewModel("","",0,"");
    }

    @Override
    public void AddProduct(ProductViewModel product) {
        this.send(ProductTopicConstants.ADD_PRODUCT, product);
    }
    private  <T> void send(T t){
        this._template.send(ProductTopicConstants.GET_PRODUCT, id);
    }
}
```